# Stripe: Get all the transactions involved in a payout paid event webhook

Tags: stripe-payments

I am subscribing to the payout.paid event of stripe.

The payout object has the following object:

```
{
  "id": "po_1H50scIkcSPJwVI7bFSQmBnV",
  "object": "payout",
  "amount": 1100,
  "arrival_date": 1594782118,
  "automatic": true,
  "balance_transaction": "txn_1H2z37IkcSPJwVI7rVwkvfCT",
  "created": 1594782118,
  "currency": "usd",
  "description": "STRIPE PAYOUT",
  "destination": "ba_1H50scIkcSPJwVI7MshqFr6u",
  "failure_balance_transaction": null,
  "failure_code": null,
  "failure_message": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "method": "standard",
  "source_type": "card",
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "status": "in_transit",
  "type": "bank_account"
}
```

Ref: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payouts/object

I am able to get this event in my webhook but I am interested in getting the transactions "involved" in this Payout.

Let's say if the payout is of $100 and I have two products of $2 and $5 each, I need to determine how many of those transactions are there from each price.

Not able to find it in docs but from the UI we can do this by going to the individual payout from the payouts screen from the "export" button beside the transactions section header:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use the "List all Balance Transactions" endpoint and specify the Payout ID there: https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/list#balance_transaction_list-payout

That way you receive a list of all balance transactions that were a part of that specific Payout.